# Are Braid groups linear as modules or as Vector spaces?

Tags: representation-theory, linear-groups, braid-groups

It is known that Braid groups are linear. I am a bit confused while understanding its linear representation.
We say that a group $G$ has linear representation if the map $\alpha: G \rightarrow GL(n,F) $ is faithful, where $GL(n, F)$ is general linear group over the field $F$. But then in the Lawrence-Krammer representation $K : B_n \rightarrow GL(m, \mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm1}, q^{\pm1}])$, $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm1}, q^{\pm1}]$ is not a field.

By Krammer's article [Braid groups are linear](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masbal/index_files/ArxivKrammer.pdf), it can be seen that the representation of the author's interest is
$ρ: B_n → GL(V )$, where $V$ is an $m$-dimensional free module over some ring $R$, with $m = n(n − 1)/2$.

So, are Braid groups linear with respect to $GL(m,F)$ or $GL(V)$?

Comment: But, the fact that the representation is faithful means that the map sending braids to matrices is an isomorphism of groups. A group of matrices is called a linear group.

Comment: A faithful representation is not necessarily bijective, so it can only be isomorphic to a subgroup of the linear group. A subgroup of invertible matrices is called a linear group.

Comment: The notation $GL(m,V)$ is confusing, presumably one should be using $GL(m,R)$ or $GL(V)$, but not $GL(m,V)$. Anyway, if $D$ is a domain (as in, an integral domain), and $\rho:G\to GL(m,D)$ is faithful, then it can be considered a faithful representation $\rho:G\to GL(m,F)$ where $F$ is the field of fractions of $D$. So it is no issue that $D$ is not a field in saying $G$ is linear. However, it confers more information to say the matrices can be chosen with elements from $D$ (for instance, not every complex rep can be expressed with integer-entry matrices, so it's meaningful info to point out).

Comment: @arctictern The notation has been edited.

Comment: @arctictern That is a neat result. Can you please provide reference, if possible. I would like to learn more.

Comment: It is trivial. If $D$ is an integral domain (i.e. a ring with no zero divisors), it is a subset of its fraction field $F$, and therefore $GL(m,D)$ is a subset of $GL(m,F)$. For example, any matrix whose entries are elements of $\Bbb Z[t^{\pm1},q^{\pm 1}]$ may be considered as a matrix whose entries are from the field $\Bbb Q(t,q)$ instead, since the former is a subset of the latter.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I was inquiring about the result " a group is linear for $GL(m,F)$, if it is linear for $GL(n,D)$ where $D$ is a subset/subgroup of $F$".

Comment: They both are the same. The link [linear representations](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation) clarifies the representation of $G$ over $F$ as the left $F[G]$-module $V$, where $F[G]$ represents a group ring over the field $F$. Further, representations of  group ring at [Representations of  group ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Representations_of_a_group_ring) shows that there is no particular reason for $F$ to be a field here.

Answer (score 1):

They both are the same. The link (https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation) clarifies the representation of $G$ over $F$ as the left $F[G]$-module, where $F[G]$ represents a group ring. Further, representations of  group ring at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Examples) shows that there is no particular reason for $R$ to be a field here.